# Php 7.1 Return Type-hint failing in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, type-hinting, laravel-5.7, php-7.1, laravel-controller

I just cloned a repository for a project I was working on. Don't quite remember the specifics of the previous machine it was running on but on this one it's using php 7.1 and I upgraded to Laravel 5.7. The issue is that in my previous machine, this piece of code was working:

```
class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() : Object
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('products.index', ['products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

**Notice** the **Object** return type.

After running migrations and everything else, when accessing index I'm getting the following error in the new machine:

> Return value of App\Http\Controllers\ProductsController::index() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Object, instance of Illuminate\View\View returned

which is related to the return type hint being Object. How do I know that? Because if I remove it everything works like charm.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for any one interested, I've got the answer from a different forum:

Simply import the class first:

```
use Illuminate\View\View;
```

and then use it as return type:

```
/**
 * @return View
 */
public function index(): View
{
    $products = Product::all();

    return view('products.index', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Comment: I have one question. Can you explain what is the use of :View after the method name?

Comment: @Yogendrasinh Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration . In strongly typed languages such as Java and C++, you must declare the type of data returned by a method. PHP is what's called 'weakly' typed language so you don't need to declare the return type. Because it's not required doesn't mean you shouldn't use it. I like to use it because adds readability to the code plus if the wrong type is returned a TypeError will be thrown. In this case, I'm specifying that whatever is returned by my method must be a View object